# How to insert a tuple into a map?

Tags: c++, iterator, tuples, c++14, std-pair

I was writing a `zip_iterator` (for fun/academic/"oh noes Boost is evil we don't want it" reasons) and one of the use cases I envisioned is zipping two `vector`s together into another container, such as a `map`. This worked on Clang with libc++, but failed unexpectedly on MSVC2017 and GCC 7.2. I reduced the problem to this code:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, double> map;

    auto it = std::inserter(map, map.begin());

    it = std::make_tuple(1, 1.);
}
```

Working demo for [Clang here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e3d76838354cd4c), broken demo's for [GCC here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3746e49632992a6b) and [MSVC here](https://godbolt.org/g/Lw1aBm).

This makes elegant use of my `zip_iterator` not work:

```
std::copy(zip_begin(ints, doubles), zip_end(ints, doubles), std::inserter(int_double_map, int_double_map.begin()));
```

See [here for the full code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a6a9088461f9473c) of that `zip_iterator` as I have it now.

I expect this to work because a tuple is a 2-pair element and one should be constructible from the other. If I try to find a generic pair(tuple) constructor, or a tuple to pair implicit conversion, I can't seem to find one. So then the question becomes: why does it work on Clang/libc++ at all?

Note: I can't just shove an `std::make_pair` in there, because, well, it's generic code.

A possible workaround would be to special-case the two-iterator case to produce a `pair` instead of a `tuple`. Seems ugly, but doable. I'd rather avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: _it's generic code_ a map will allways use std::pair. Where is the generic part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> and one should be constructible from the other

- [`std::pair<T, U>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) does not define any implicit constructor from `std::tuple<T, U>`.
- Similarly, [`std::tuple<T, U>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) does not
  define any implicit conversion operator to `std::pair<T, U>`.

I think Clang (libc++) is incorrect here, and that GCC and MSVC are correct.

---

> Seems ugly, but doable

It's not too bad:

```
template <typename... Ts> 
auto make_thing(Ts&&... xs)
{
    if constexpr(sizeof...(xs) == 2)) 
    { 
        return std::make_pair(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::make_tuple(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);
    } 
}
```

In C++14, you can replace `if constexpr` with specialization/`enable_if` or [**`static_if`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aXSsUqVSe2k).

Comment: Doesn't libc++ just provide a conforming extension? Or is it really incorrect?

Comment: @rubenvb if it doesn't issue a diagnostic message (a warning) when it is used, then the extension doesn't conform.

Comment: You are linking to the wrong page for `std::tuple` :P

Comment: @Vittoreo yeah, that's pretty much what I had in mind :).